# Remove lines that contains repeated regular expression in perl

Tags: regex, perl, duplicates, unique

I have an array that contains elements like:

```
@array = qw/ john jim rocky hosanna/;
```

#### INPUT FILE:

```
john wears blue shirt 

hosanna knows drawing

george and jim went to europe

john went to swimming

jim wears yellow shirt

rocky went to swimming

rocky learns painting

hosanna learns painting
```

#### REQUIRED OUTPUT:

```
john wears blue shirt 

hosanna knows drawing

george and jim went to europe

rocky went to swimming
```

so, I need to have only first occurrences lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -ane 'print unless $a{$F[0]}++ ' inputfile
```

hope this works +

Answer (score 4):

```
@seen{@array} = ();
@out = grep { (($w)=split; !($seen{$w}++) } @in;
```

Comment: one more thing, if the array elements were found in the middle of the file. Ex : george and john went to europe ... it wont delete that line –

Comment: @user1228191 - use an internal grep of the split result, or a regex anchored by `\b` word boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

What about making another array which indicates if the name was already used? Then, first time you read line with Jim, set variable in this array as used and write in into output. If it was already used in the past, do nothing.

```
@array =(john,jim,rocky,hosanna);
@used =(0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way. I save array data to a hash and delete an entry when found in the input file.

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

## Input names to search.
my @array = qw/ john jim rocky hosanna/;

## Save names to a hash. This way they are easier to find out.
my %names = map { $_ => 1 } @array;

## Read file line by line.
while ( <> ) { 

    ## Avoid blank lines.
    next if m/\A\s*\Z/;

    ## Split line in fields.
    my @f = split;

    ## Count number of names in hash.
    my $num_entries = scalar keys %names;

    ## Remove words of hash found in line.
    for ( @f ) { 
        delete $names{ $_ };
    }   

    ## If now there are less names, it means that line had any of
    ## them, so print line.
    if ( scalar keys %names < $num_entries ) { 
        printf qq[%s\n], $_; 
    }   

    ## If hash is empty, there are no lines left to print, so exit of
    ## loop without checking more lines.
    last if scalar keys %names == 0;
}
```

Command:

```
perl script.pl infile
```

Output:

```
john wears blue shirt 

hosanna knows drawing

george and jim went to europe

rocky went to swimming
```

Comment: Thanks so much, works awesome!! Warnings like Unquoted string "john" may clash with future reserved word at script.pl line 3.  Will this warning effect later when working on large files

Comment: @user1228191 That comes from your own line: `@array =(john,jim,rocky ,hosanna)`, where you forgot to add `qw` before the parens.

Comment: Thanksss!! one more thing, if the array elements were found in the middle of the file. Ex : george and john went to europe ... it wont delete that line

Comment: i had generalised my question, please check!!